# React.js State Variable not updating on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am using a state variable to track whether an icon has been hovered over.  The variable is not updating.  Console.log of the state variable is not working either (it doesn't show in console)

```
Icons = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        return { icon_id: 0};
        console.log(icon_id);
    },

    onHover: function(event) {
        this.setState({ icon_id: event.currentTarget.dataset.id });
        console.log(icon_id);
    },

    render: function() {

        return (

        <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="example" transitionAppear={true} transitionLeave={true} transitionEnterTimeout={600} transitionAppearTimeout={600} transitionLeaveTimeout={300}>


                    <ul className="someclass">{ iconslist.map(function(i){
                            return <li key={i.id}><a href={i.url} target="_blank"><span className={i.class} id={i.id} data-id={i.data} onMouseOver={this.onHover}></span></a></li>

                        }) }

                    </ul>
                    <p className="icon-text">{iconslist[this.state.icon_id].name}</p>


        </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>

        );

    }

});

var ReactCSSTransitionGroup = React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup;

var iconslist = [

    { data: '0', url: 'mailto:******', id: 'lightbulb', class: 'fa fa-lightbulb-o fa-5x', name: 'Thoughts'},
    { data: '1', url: 'mailto:******', id: 'gears', class: 'fa fa-gears fa-5x', name: 'ML'},
];
```

Comment: Have you tried to console "event.currentTarget.dataset.id" , is that working ?

Answer (score 0):

You should access any state variable as follows:

```
var iconid = this.state.icon_id;
console.log(iconid);
```

Comment: It's still not showing up in the console.  Also it is not changing the data on hover.  Any idea why?

Comment: you need to bind this to your function as follows:


return <li key={i.id}><a href={i.url} target="_blank"><span className={i.class} id={i.id} data-id={i.data} onMouseOver={this.onHover.bind(this)}></span></a></li>

Comment: It says: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

Comment: I'm seeing that the onMouseOver event isn't working.  I put console.log("hello") in there and it still isn't triggering.

Answer (score 0):

The `setState` method does not immediately update the state of the class. So the `setState` method also take a callback which is invoked after react has updated the state - [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

So in your code, you'd have to do something like this:

```
onHover: function(event) {
    this.setState({ 
      icon_id: event.currentTarget.dataset.id 
    }, () => console.log(icon_id));
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to a little change your code. You have to bind this method because this doesn’t know about that method. Take a look what I changed.

```
      getInitialState: function() {
        return { icon_id: 0};
        console.log(icon_id);
    },

    onHover = (event) => {
        this.setState({ icon_id: event.currentTarget.dataset.id });
        console.log(icon_id);
    },

    render: function() {

        return (

        <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="example" transitionAppear={true} transitionLeave={true} transitionEnterTimeout={600} transitionAppearTimeout={600} transitionLeaveTimeout={300}>


                    <ul className="someclass">{ iconslist.map(function(i){
                            return <li key={i.id}><a href={i.url} target="_blank"><span className={i.class} id={i.id} data-id={i.data} onMouseOver={() => this.onHover()}></span></a></li>

                        }) }

                    </ul>
                    <p className="icon-text">{iconslist[this.state.icon_id].name}</p>


        </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>

        );
```

That should works, if You use arrow function You don’t need to bind function.

Comment: So I made the change, and on hover I got this error now: Uncaught TypeError: _this.onHover is not a function

Answer (score 0):

None of these answers were correct.  I figured it out.

Instead of using the "function" term inside the render function, I had to use:

```
<ul className="icons">{ iconslist.map((i) => {
                            return (
                            <li key={i.id}>
                                <span className={i.class} 
                                    id={i.id} 
                                    data-id={i.data} 
                                    onMouseOver={this.onHover}>
                                </span>
                            </li>
                            )
                        }) }

                    </ul>
```

Using (i) => in the map function is what did it.

No soup for anyone else in this thread.